# Backtesting EGARCH-NIG CVaR in R

Tags: programming, garch, cvar, normal-inverse-gaussian

I fitted an EGARCH model with a NIG distribution to a series of returns.

Using the following link I tried got how I should calculate the CVaR of the model

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/CVaR-with-NIG-GARCH-1-1-td4666903.html

The answer was from the person that created the rugarch package, which stunned me.

Anyway, I calculated the CVaR at each step as he exlained and I plotted the returns and the CVaR vector together the CVaR vector is filled with very small values, much smaller then the return values how can this be ? What am I doing wrong ?

The code I used is the following:

```
exon <- as.data.frame(Ad(getSymbols("XOM", src="yahoo", adjust = T, auto.assign = F, to = "2019-04-01"))) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  setNames(c("Date", "EXXON")) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Date)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

returns_df <- as.data.frame(diff(log(exon$EXXON)))

n <- round((80 * nrow(returns_df))/100,0)
sarima_train <- returns_df %>% head(n)

egarch_spec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 3), include.mean = T),
                         variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                         distribution.model="nig")

egarch_fit <- ugarchfit(spec = egarch_spec, data = sarima_train[,"diff(log(exon$EXXON))"])

res_roll <- ugarchroll(egarch_spec, sarima_train[,"diff(log(exon$EXXON))"],n.start = 750, refit.every = 50, refit.window = "moving",
                           solver = "hybrid", calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05), keep.coef = T,
                           solver.control = ctrl, fit.control = list(scale = 1))

gnigdist <- as.data.frame(res_roll, which = 'density')

f <- function(x, mu, sigma, skew, shape){
  return(mu + qdist("nig", p=x, mu, sigma, skew=skew, shape=shape)*sigma)
}

es_nig <- function(p = 0.05){

  mu <- gnigdist[, 'Mu'] 
  sigma <- gnigdist[, 'Sigma'] 
  shape <- gnigdist[, 'Shape'] 
  skew <- gnigdist[, 'Skew'] 
  lambda <- gnigdist[, 'Shape(GIG)']
  ES <- rep(0, length(mu))
  for(i in 1:length(mu)) {

    ES[i] <- integrate(f, 0, p, mu = mu[i], sigma=sigma[i], shape = 
                      shape[i], skew=skew[i])$value/p 
  }
  return(ES)
}


exxon_es <- es_nig()

plot(tail(sarima_train[,"diff(log(exon$EXXON))"],1420))
lines(exxon_es, col = "red")
```

As you will see you will get the follwing plot :

[image]

And the CVaR values (in red) are really small compared to the real returns (in black)

Can someone please enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The qdist function turned out to be standardized and so the VaR function is:

```
f <- function(x, mu, sigma, skew, shape){
  return(qdist("nig", p=x, mu =mu , sigma = sigma, skew=skew, shape=shape))
}
```

Making this adjustment to the f function and then proceeding the same way you will obtain a good graph for the CVaR

```
es_nig <- function(p = 0.05){

  mu <- gnigdist[, 'Mu'] 
  sigma <- gnigdist[, 'Sigma'] 
  shape <- gnigdist[, 'Shape'] 
  skew <- gnigdist[, 'Skew'] 
  lambda <- gnigdist[, 'Shape(GIG)']
  ES <- rep(0, length(mu))
  for(i in 1:length(mu)) {

    ES[i] <- integrate(f, 0, p, mu = mu[i], sigma=sigma[i], shape = 
                      shape[i], skew=skew[i])$value/p 
  }
  return(ES)
}


exxon_es <- es_nig()

plot(tail(sarima_train[,"diff(log(exon$EXXON))"],1420))
lines(exxon_es, col = "red")
```